# AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-storage

```
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://my_bucket/
```

command gives `AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden` error even I provide full access to my email id as owner to my_bucket.I am using blobstore api to upload the file in my project. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set up Cloud API access for your virtual machine. Currently it needs to be set during VM creation process by enabling:

```
Allow full access to all Cloud APIs
```

To provide access for VM when you haven't chosen the above setting you need to recreate instance with full access, but there is pending improvement:

[Google Cloud Platform Ability to change API access scopes](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/13101552-ability-to-change-cloud-api-access-scopes-on-launc)

When it's done we will be able to change settings after shutting down instance.